# Embed Google Map

Tags: 7, google-maps

When I generate the map and paste it on the site, it shows me only the "View Larger Map" link.

How can I embed Google Map into my Drupal 7 site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that your text gets filtered. Are you trying to embed the  given by the google maps web? If that it's the case, check that the text-format of your node is 'full html'.

You can also take a look into the OpenLayers module to add maps into nodes:

> http://drupal.org/project/openlayers

Answer (score 0):

if you want google maps you can use this module: http://drupal.org/project/gmap.
There is also a great screen cast that shows how to use it:
http://www.drupaltherapy.com/gmap

Answer (score 0):

For a single map at a brochure site try the simple [Location Map Module](http://drupal.org/project/locationmap).

Answer (score 0):

Drupal doesn't seem to render iFrame code correctly. You can embed a Google Map by using an object tag instead of iFrame. Example:

```
<object id="map" type="text/html" data="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=..." style="width:450px;height:300px;">
```